# Grouped table causing sum() to multiple result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Maybe it's just because it's really late and this is probably something super simple but I'm having an issue with my query:

```
$lead = Lead::findOrFail($id);
$recipients = Recipient::with('segment')
    ->select('recipients.*',
        DB::raw('coalesce(rulesets.name, "Accept any...") as ruleset_name'),
        DB::raw('coalesce(sum(recipient_leads.leads_left), 0) as leads_left'),
        DB::raw('round(min('.((configuration('location_distance_unit') == 'km') ? '6371' : '3959').' * acos(cos(radians('.$lead->latitude.')) * cos(radians(recipient_locations.latitude)) * cos(radians(recipient_locations.longitude) - radians('.$lead->longitude.')) + sin(radians('.$lead->latitude.')) * sin(radians(recipient_locations.latitude))))) as distance'))
    ->leftJoin('rulesets', 'rulesets.id', '=', 'recipients.ruleset_id')
    ->leftJoin('recipient_leads', 'recipient_leads.recipient_id', '=', 'recipients.id')
    ->leftJoin('recipient_locations', 'recipient_locations.recipient_id', '=', 'recipients.id')
    ->where('recipients.segment_id', $lead->segment_id)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($lead) {
        $query->whereIn('recipients.ruleset_id', $lead->rulesetIds())->orWhereNull('recipients.ruleset_id');
    })
    ->whereRaw('distance <= recipient_locations.distance')
    ->where('recipients.active', true)
    ->where('leads_left', '>', 0)
    ->groupBy('recipients.id');
```

My issue is that the `leads_left` sum appears to get multiplied by the amount of `recipient_locations` there are. I've tried adding `recipient_locations.recipient_id` and `recipient_leads.recipient_id` to my groupBy and it had no effect.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

**Edit: here is the raw query:**

```
select 
    `recipients`.*, 
    coalesce(rulesets.name, "Accept any...") as ruleset_name, 
    coalesce(sum(recipient_leads.leads_left), 0) as leads_left, 
    round(min(6371 * acos(cos(radians(43.8988057)) * cos(radians(recipient_locations.latitude)) * cos(radians(recipient_locations.longitude) - radians(-78.6974833)) + sin(radians(43.8988057)) * sin(radians(recipient_locations.latitude))))) as distance 
from `recipients` 
left join `rulesets` on `rulesets`.`id` = `recipients`.`ruleset_id` 
left join `recipient_leads` on `recipient_leads`.`recipient_id` = `recipients`.`id` 
left join `recipient_locations` on `recipient_locations`.`recipient_id` = `recipients`.`id` 
where `recipients`.`segment_id` = ? and (`recipients`.`ruleset_id` in (?, ?) or `recipients`.`ruleset_id` is null) and distance <= recipient_locations.distance and `recipients`.`active` = ? and `leads_left` > ? 
group by `recipients`.`id`
```

Comment: Try having instead where

Comment: is it a many to many relationship, it's probably cartesian product

Comment: this is Eloquent? I hate query builders, so ugly and hard to optimize the query.

Comment: I need to query using the haversine formula. I have to use the query builder. All I want to know is why its multiplying the sum of leads_left when it shouldn't.

Comment: I've added the actual SQL query to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not going to attempt to rewrite the whole query, but your problem is that when you're using multiple left joins like that, matching rows from the left are duplicated on the right (which is why your sum is wrong).

If you calculate the `sum` BEFORE the joins, it should work the way you want to.

Actually here is a previous answer that explains it pretty well:

[Using SUM with multiple joins in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115867/using-sum-with-multiple-joins-in-mysql)

Comment: Calculating sum before the join worked perfectly. E.G. `(select coalesce(sum(leads_left), 0) from recipient_leads where recipient_id=recipients.id) as leads_left`

Comment: Glad to know that solved your problem, I've had a similar issue a few weeks ago and remembered that post above :)